# What is the data shape that this RNN architecture will take as input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Complete noob to RNN.

I came across this code on web:

```
def buildModel(dataLength, labelLength):

    height = Input(shape=(dataLength, 1), name="height")
    weight = Input(shape=(dataLength, 1), name="weight")

    heightLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(height)
    weightLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(weight)

    output = concatenate([ heightLayers, weightLayers ])

    output = Dense(labelLength, activation="linear", name="weightedAverage_output")(output)

    model = Model(
        inputs=[height, weight],
        outputs=[output]
        )

    model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse")

    return model
```

I'm supposed to enter in time series data as numpy array, but I am not sure what's the expected numpy array shape here height/weight

I passed in something like

```
[[[ 0]
  [ 1]
  [ 2]
  [ 3]
  [ 4]
  ....
  [ 10]]]
```

and it's giving me this error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected close to have shape (None, 60, 1) but got array with shape (2, 45, 1)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an input of shape `(batch_size, dataLength, 1)` twice as an input. In this specific case it is `(batch_size, 60, 1)`.

Now, `batch_size` is how many data points you are going to use to update the weights. It could be 1 or it could be n (all of your data). Most common batch_size are powers of 2 so `64` or `128` should be ok if you are unsure. (The error says `None` because it doesn't have a strict shape requirement)

`dataLength` is your problem specific and it's dataLengthx2 because your `heightLayers` cell and `weightLayers` cell wants to get a height input with size dataLength and your weight input with size of dataLength. You can see this on:

```
model = Model(
    inputs=[height, weight], # requested input shape is height + weight
    outputs=[output]         # outputs a tensor of shape labelLength
    )
```

If you just want to run and see if the model is working you can give something like this and it should work:

```
[numpy.zeros((32,30,1)), numpy.zeros((32,30,1))] # one for height, one for width
```

---

**Edit:** Second look to your error and it looks like it requires an input with shape of `(batch_size, 60, 1)`. It looks like it wants the arrays concatenated (it acts differently on my setup, requires a list of two inputs). 
So you should try:

```
np.zeros((32,60,1))
```

and see if it works.

---

**Edit 2:** Sorry I've misinterpreted your inputs on my first view. Looking at the pastebin you've posted. Your `dataLength` is 60. So the network expects two numpy arrays with `(batch_size, dataLength, 1)` shape.

So this should work:

```
batch_input = [np.zeros((32,60,1)), np.zeros((32,60,1))]
batch_labels = np.ones((32,4))
model.fit(batch_input, batch_labels)
```

Oh and important addition, if you are using keras you can call `model.summary()` for more insight about your layers structure. In this case it should show that it starts with 2 input layers, each requiring `(None, 60, 1)` shape.

Comment: @TaeWoo Sorry I must've misinterpreted your inputs, from what I see on the pastebin you can use `model.fit([np.zeros((32,60,1)), np.zeros((32,60,1))], np.ones((32,4)))` and it works on my computer. I'll edit the post for details.

Comment: Yes, that works. Im confused by (32, 60, 1). Does this mean that this input is looking for  1-dimensional time series with 60 points, and total of 32 of them? if so, do these 32 have to be in sequential sliding window like this? https://pastebin.com/KEynPuv0